# Powershell studio datagridview if statement

Tags: powershell, datagridview

I have a cellpainting event and am trying to correct/clean this IF statement up.  I think I'm getting lost in my parenthess. Is someone able to take a second look at this?  Thanks for your time.

My end goal is the IF statemant to be: Column 1 date older than 42 days or not $null **and** column 4 value = "SEP"

```
$datagridview1_CellPainting=[System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler]{

    $SEPreturnlimit = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" -f (get-date).AddDays(-42)
    if ((($_.ColumnIndex -eq 1 -and ([datetime]$_.Value -le $SEPreturnlimit -and [datetime]$_.Value.ToString() -ne $null))) -and ($datagridview1.rows .Cells[4].Value -eq "SEP")) #Column 1 date older than 42 days or not $null **and** column 4 value = "SEP"
    {
        $this.Rows[$_.RowIndex] | %{ $_.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 'crimson' } #Color Row
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the if conditions into separate nested `if`s and also add a `try..catch`

```
$datagridview1_CellPainting = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler] {

    if ($_.ColumnIndex -eq 1 -and $datagridview1.rows.Cells[4].Value -eq 'SEP') {
        $SEPreturnlimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-42).Date   # set to 42 days back at midnight
        try {
            # if we succeed in parsing out a datetime object
            $date = [datetime]$_.Value
            # test if we have a DateTime object and if that date is older than the reference date
            if (($date) -and $date-le $SEPreturnlimit) {
                # cannot check this myself, but shouldn't that simply be
                # $this.Rows[$_.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 'crimson'
                $this.Rows[$_.RowIndex] | ForEach-Object{ $_.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 'crimson' } #Color Row
            }
        }
        catch { <# do nothing #> }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed the placement, but check the logic.  Have a look at it this way

```
if 
(
    (
        $_.ColumnIndex -eq 1 -and
        (
            [datetime]$_.Value -le
            $SEPreturnlimit -and
            [datetime]$_.Value.ToString() -ne
            $null
        )
    ) -and
    (
        $datagridview1.rows .Cells[4].Value -eq
        'SEP'
    )
) #Column 1 date older than 42 days or not $null **and** column 4 value = "SEP"
```

Comment: Thank you. Looking at this way is easier to view placement for me.  I don't think I'm declaring this part of it correctly now  $datagridview1.rows.Cells[4].Value -eq 'SEP'.  Trying to work through this part yet..

Comment: To access the cell values there are multiple ways actually.  I'm not sure what the range is on your $datagridview1 object or even if it is a range.  If it is and you are looking for the value in the first row, 4th column it would be something like `$datagridview1.Rows(1).Columns(4).Value2` or `$datagridview1.Cells(1,4).Value2`.